# java left integer pad with zero

Tags: java, integer, format

How can I get an Integer to be two digits. If it's under 10 it would show 01,02, etc. I want to keep the Integer as an Integer. String.format gives a string. How can I do this with Decimalformat for ex

```
Decimalformat df = new Decimalformat(???);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the value as an `int` or `Integer`, there's nothing to be done here. A number doesn't *have* a format - it just has a value. For example, an `int` isn't "in decimal" or "in hex" or "in binary" - if you write

```
int x = 16;
int y = 0x10;
```

those are the *exact* same values.

The idea of "padding" only makes any sense when it comes to a textual representation of the number - which is when you end up with a string.

Comment: That's what I suspected. It was for my sql query that uses integers. Problem solved, I just change the parameter from integer to a string

Comment: @Waffles.Inc: You shouldn't do that - if you've got a SQL query which uses integers, the textual representation should be irrelevant. It sounds like you've probably got strings *somewhere* that they shouldn't be.

Comment: It's for my sql query that looks like this "SELECT * FROM " +TABLE_PRODUCTS +" WHERE DATE BETWEEN '" + year  + "-"+ startMonth  + "-" + startDay+ "' AND '"  
    +year + "-" + endMonth + "-" + endDay + "'"          And if the date does not have two integers the query does not work

Comment: @Waffles.Inc: Well you should *start* by avoiding building SQL like that. Always, always, always use parameterized SQL. In this case, you want date parameters - so use `java.sql.Date` to represent the start and end values.

Comment: Ok, I need to take a look at that because I did not learn that yet.

Answer (score 1):

you do something likewise, but directly you can't get into `int or Integer`

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("00");  
String s = formatter.format(1); // ----> 01
```